# react native + redux (update status for other components to hear on the same screen)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, redux, react-redux

I have a query with redux + react native ..
I have a redux state that contains data, that data is constantly changing.
I also have several components that need to read this data.
The question is that all the components are on the screen, and when one makes a modification to the redux state, this must be reflected in the others too, I can not find any solution, the best thing would be something that makes the components render again that they are listening to the state but I can't do it .. I need help!

Comment: please provide the more Infos. Describe what you’ve tried, Show some code. @ivanzapata

Answer (score 0):

Try to use event emitter for call methods to get data from methods in all components.

Ref link:- https://medium.com/@filipedegrazia/using-custom-events-in-react-native-831a809f279d

Event emitter emits an event from one component to another to call any function or pass data also. Call get method in all components to emit method after data changed.

Comment: This solution no longer works, since React Native doesn’t include the Node Standard Library   :(